# Try to print frame '*' and diagonal in python

Tags: python, io, frame

I try to print '*' in frame and in diagonal .

This is what I did:

```
x=10
y=10
def print_frame(n, m, c):
  print c * m
  for i in range(1, n - 1):
    print c ,' '*(n-2-i),c, ' '*i , c  , c
  print c * m

print_frame(10, 10, '*')
```

This is the result:

```
**********
*         *   * *
*        *    * *
*       *     * *
*      *      * *
*     *       * *
*    *        * *
*   *         * *
*  *          * *
**********
```

Comment: Please give an example of the expected output, and *why you think your code isn't working*.

Comment: Only a square matrix has a diagonal. Are you sure you don't want a square frame (`def print_frame(n, c):`)? It's possible with rectangular frames as well, but it's more complex and diagonals won't look like straight lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I specified in my comment, only square matrices have diagonals. But even for those, things are "a bit" more complex than they seem:

- I could have done it in a single loop, but I think it's better to see all the "sections"
- The (string) calculations could have been written in a more compact way, but I left them as they are for clarity
- Also added the recursive variant. I prefer this one as it's clearer (although in general, recursion has limitations), especially since given the nature of the problem, the recursion doesn't go deep enough in order to generate *StackOverflow*, or to have a negative effect on performance
- Instead of printing the string inside the function, I "return" them. That is an optimization technique: if they are needed in more than one place, the function only needs to be called once
- The functions are generators (*yield* instead of *return*). That is also an optimization (and it's *Python*ic)

*code01.py*:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys


def square_frame_iterative(side, char="*"):
    yield char * side  # Upper row
    for i in range(1, side - 1):
        edge_space = min(i - 1, side - 2 - i)
        mid_space = side - 2 * edge_space - 4
        mid_text = char if mid_space < 0 else char + " " * mid_space + char
        yield char + " " * edge_space + mid_text + " " * edge_space + char
    yield char * side  # Lower row


# Recursion
def _square_frame_recursive(side, char, i):
    if i == side // 2 - 1:
        if side % 2 :
            yield char + " " * ((side - 3) // 2) + char + " " * ((side - 3) // 2) + char  # Mid row
    else:
        s = char + " " * i + char + " " * (side - 2 * i - 4) + char + " " * i + char
        yield s
        yield from _square_frame_recursive(side, char, i + 1)
        yield s


def square_frame_recursive(side, char="*"):
    yield char * side  # Upper row
    if side <= 1:
        return
    yield from _square_frame_recursive(side, char, 0)
    yield char * side  # Lower row

# Recursion end


def main(argv):
    dim = 10
    square_frame_func = square_frame_iterative
    if argv:
        if argv[0].isdigit():
            dim = int(argv[0])
        if (len(argv) > 1) and argv[1].lower().startswith("rec"):
            square_frame_func = square_frame_recursive
    frame_string = "\n".join(square_frame_func(dim))
    print(frame_string)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {0:s} {1:d}bit on {2:s}\n".format(" ".join(item.strip() for item in sys.version.split("\n")), 64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    main(sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.")
```

**Output**:

> ```bat
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q055342983]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.07.03_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code01.py
> Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 22:22:05) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] 64bit on win32
>
> **********
> **      **
> * *    * *
> *  *  *  *
> *   **   *
> *   **   *
> *  *  *  *
> * *    * *
> **      **
> **********
>
> Done.
>
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q055342983]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.07.03_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code01.py 7 rec
> Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 22:22:05) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] 64bit on win32
>
> *******
> **   **
> * * * *
> *  *  *
> * * * *
> **   **
> *******
>
> Done.
> ```