# How do I print this dynamic pattern using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing

Ask user to input an 'odd' number greater than or equal to 5 (>=5), and write a block of code to display a square using asterisks that is divided into four triangles.

See examples below to understand the behaviour of the pattern: 
For example for number 5, the pattern is:

```
*****
** **
* * *
** **
*****
```

For example for number 9, the pattern is:

```
*********
**     **
* *   * *
*  * *  *
*   *   *
*  * *  *
* *   * *
**     **
*********
```

I tried numerous combinations of code but in vain. I am using the Python 3.7.3 version.

```
n = int(input("Please enter an odd number greater than or equal to 5: "))

while(n < 5 or n%2==0):
    print("Invalid")
    break

else:    
    for a in range(n):
        if(a==0 or a==n-1):

            print("*"*n,end='')
        else:

            i=1

            j=n-1

            for row in range(n-1):

                for col in range(n-1):

                    if(row==i and col==j):

                        print("*",end="")

                        i=i+1

                        j=j-1
                    elif row==col:
                        print("*",end="")
                    else:
                        print(end="")
                print()
```

I am clearly doing something wrong here and not getting desired output

Comment: Problems like this are much easier to start solving on paper before writing your code. Stop, look for patterns in the behaviour, and then it will become much more clear.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Try to print frame '\*' and diagonal in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55342983/try-to-print-frame-and-diagonal-in-python)

Comment: You are doing rather well. Two hints: a) Don't touch `i` and `j`, let the loops take care of changing them. b) Just printing asterisks won't help, you also need some spaces. `print(end="")` does nothing useful.

Comment: you have to print spaces to move `*` in correct place.

Comment: Also, while your 'while' construct in the  beginning does work, it would be much cleaner to replace it with `if n < 5 or n%2==0:` and remove the `break`.

Comment: Start easy and try breaking your code. I might use four loops to start with. Two to print top and bottom border and other two to print two triangles in mid. After this you can start optimizing your code

Comment: @Saharsh the top and bottom border doesn't require a loop, and printing the borders already works, if OP removes the `end=""` from the respective print statements.

Comment: I think your biggest thought mistake is that you iterate over rows twice. `for a in range(n)` is already an iteration over all rows, and `for row in range(n-1)` does it again. Your `else:` case  after the `print("*"*n,end='')` doesn't have to print the entire inner body, only one single line, with the line id `a`. For example, if your side length is 5, at the iteration where `a` is `1` this code has to print `**  **`.
Another annotation that I have is that I would not only make `a==0` and `a==n-1` special cases, but also `a==(n-1)//2`.

Comment: @Finomnis I agree. That's why I said you can think of optimization part later on.

Comment: @Saharsh I don't think that was meant as an optimization.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
n = int(input("Please enter an odd number greater than or equal to 5: "))
while(n < 5 or n%2==0):
  print("Invalid")
  n = int(input("Please enter an odd number greater than or equal to 5: "))

x = ['*'*n] + ['*'+' '*i+'*'+' '*(n-4-i*2)+'*'+' '*i+'*' for i in range(int((n-3)/2))]
print('\n'.join(x + ['*'+' '*int((n-3)/2)+'*'+' '*int((n-3)/2)+'*'] + x[::-1]))
```